# TypeScript Compiler looking at external directory for node_modules

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, node-modules, tsc

I have an angular 2 project that lives in a directory:
 **/c/users/batcave/first_project**.

In that direcotory I have my app folder, index.html, systemjs.config.js ..etc, and node_modules folder but ONLY with @types and typescript. This means my @angular and other dependencies live in another directory: **/c/users/dep/node_modules**.

I have updated my systemjs.config.js file to look in this different directory on runtime but my question is for compilation. How do I tell tsc to not look in the node_modules folder it's currently in but to look in a specified external directory: **/c/users/dep/node_modules**?

I tried setting the baseUrl setting in tsconfig.json but no luck. Since tsconfig lives in **/c/users/batcave/first_project**, I tried to set the relative path for the external nodes_module to **../../dep/**

Answer (score -1):

I do not have setup like this. But what you need is probably `include`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "/c/users/dep/node_moodules"
  ]
}
```